# How to do my range silder to work on touch screen on asp.net mvc 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web site in asp.net mvc 3 razor and have some range sliders. This range sliders work fine but not to touch screens.
My Html code:

```
<div id="slider-container-zucker" class="slider_style"></div>
```

and js:

```
$(function () {
var str = document.URL.split("/");
var url = str[0] + "//" + str[2];

$('#slider-container-zucker').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 9,
    values: [$("#zuckerMin").val(), $("#zuckerMax").val()],
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url + "/Slider/Zucker?max=" + ui.values[1] + "&min=" + ui.values[0],
            success: function (result) {
                $("#wineResult").html(result);
            }
        });            
        $('#sliderImage').load(url + "/Slider/ChangeSlider?max=" + ui.values[1] + "&min=" + ui.values[0] + "&sliderName=zucker");
    }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add more this jquery library 
you must see it here: 
https://github.com/ghusse/jquery-ui-touch-punch/blob/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

```
/*
* jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.2
*
* Copyright 2011, Dave Furfero
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
*
* Depends:
*  jquery.ui.widget.js
*  jquery.ui.mouse.js
*/
(function(b){b.support.touch="ontouchend" in document;if(!b.support.touch){return;}var c=b.ui.mouse.prototype,e=c._mouseInit,a;function d(g,h){if(g.originalEvent.touches.length>1){return;}g.preventDefault();var i=g.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],f=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");f.initMouseEvent(h,true,true,window,1,i.screenX,i.screenY,i.clientX,i.clientY,false,false,false,false,0,null);g.target.dispatchEvent(f);}c._touchStart=function(g){var f=this;if(a||!f._mouseCapture(g.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])){return;}a=true;f._touchMoved=false;d(g,"mouseover");d(g,"mousemove");d(g,"mousedown");};c._touchMove=function(f){if(!a){return;}this._touchMoved=true;d(f,"mousemove");};c._touchEnd=function(f){if(!a){return;}d(f,"mouseup");d(f,"mouseout");if(!this._touchMoved){d(f,"click");}a=false;};c._mouseInit=function(){var f=this;f.element.bind("touchstart",b.proxy(f,"_touchStart")).bind("touchmove",b.proxy(f,"_touchMove")).bind("touchend",b.proxy(f,"_touchEnd"));e.call(f);};})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Where I must to include this library?

Comment: this library you must to put it in a js file snd add it in Scripts folder and for call it use in html:<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/youfilename.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>